# How to make eclipse view completely not closeable?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In my Eclipse RCP application I have a view that should never be closed.
For remove "Close" button from view title and not allow to detach view (after this user can close detached window) I have added lines

```java
layout.getViewLayout("my_view_id").setCloseable(false);
layout.getViewLayout("my_view_id").setMoveable(false);
```

in

```java
createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) { ... }
```

method of perspective class.

But one more way to close view remains: user can minimize view and after this close it via context menu of minimized icon:

[image: close context menu]

How can I remove "Close" menu item from context menu or not allow to show context menu on minimized view?

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add the view using Perspective Extension and set the "Closable" Property as false 
[This is a image showing the Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJzpS.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This should actually be a comment, not an answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation. Thanks.